# Return values in same row by searching different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given data like this:

```
    A    B      C    D
1   MAX. Time   MIN. Time
2   140  08:00  100  01:00     
3   150  15:00  50   02:00
4   130  17:00  80   03:00  
5   120  22:00  90   04:00
```

`=MAX(A2:A5)` will return 150 and
`=MIN(C2:C5)` will return 50

How can I find the values in COL B in same row as 150 (for MAX) and in COL D in the same row as 50 (for MIN)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can confirm that you have only one max(min) value (if not, formula returns first occurance), you can simply use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx):

```
=VLOOKUP(Max(A2:A5),A2:B5,2,0)
```

for min formulaa would be the same:

```
=VLOOKUP(Min(C2:C5),C2:D5,2,0)
```

Alternatively you can use more flexible formula:

```
=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(Min(C2:C5),C2:C5,0))
```

above formula finds min in column C and returns corresponding value from col B